# Friend circle by sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Say i have the following `Users` model-

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__='users'
    id=Column(Integer, primary=True)
    friends=relationship(
        'Users',
        secondary='friend_associations',
        primaryjoin='and_(FriendAssociations.user_id==Users.id,'
            'FriendAssociations.pending==False)',
        secondaryjoin='and_(FriendAssociations.friend_id==Users.id,'
            'FriendAssociations.pending==False)',
        uselist=True,
    )
```

And the `FriendAssociations` model is-

```
class FriendAssociations(Base):
    __tablename__='friend_associations'
    id=Column(Integer, primary=True)
    user_id=Column(ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id=Column(ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    pending=Column(Boolean, default=True)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(
        'user_id','friend_id', name='uq_user_friend_id_pair'
    ),)
```

The target was, user A sends a friend request to user B. Until user B accepts the request, the request stays as pending. When B accepts the request, `pending` is `False` and one more `friend_associations` entry 
is created on user B to state that user A is friend of user B and vice versa. The problem is, i can do these things, but when i want to remove a user entry, the database(i am using PostgreSQL) throws up error saying `friend_associations` depends on the user(because the association entry isn't deleted). As a result i can't delete any user entry.

So -

1. Is my solution to the problem correct?
2. If not, what should i do to correct it?
3. Please give basic query examples like adding, deleting friends and user entries with such solution or mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read on [cascades](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html), especially [delete](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete) and DB side [ON DELETE](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#on-update-and-on-delete) cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution reading the docs a little more. combining cascade, single_parent and passive_deletes i could achieve 3 relationships -

1. `friends` - who have accepted friend request
2. `sent_friend_requests` - who are sent a request from the user and yet havent accepted
3. `awaiting_friend_requests` - who have sent request to the user and yet not accepted

Thumbs up for SQLAlchemy documentations.